# VBA Code to Evaluate Sumproduct in a dynamic TABLE

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a data entry form to store information in a table. I am trying to get the sumproduct of values contained in a table which time a user submits an entry (from the userform).

I have tried specifying my range, e.g G6:G1000 which worked but i want it to capture only the values contained in the table.

```
Sheet1.Range("P7").Value = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(range("G6", range("G5").End(xlDown), SUBTOTAL(109, OFFSET(H6, ROW(range("H6", range("H5").End(xlDown)-ROW(H6),)))")
```

I get a compile error: Expected list separator or )

Comment: You have more ( than ) Also ROW(H6),))) - seems like just a loose comma

Comment: You're mixing VBA (`Range` and `End` calls) and Worksheet formulas. That's the bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass the address of the range to the formula.  The formula is a string and one cannot pass a range object into a string, so we pass the address.

Also we want to ensure the correct sheet on everything so we use the With block:

```
With Sheet1      
    .Range("P7").Value = .Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(" & .Range("G6", .Range("G5").End(xlDown)).Address(0, 0) & ", SUBTOTAL(109, OFFSET(H6, ROW(" & .Range("H6", .Range("H5").End(xlDown)).Address(0, 0) & ")-ROW(H6),)))")
End With
```

Comment: Looks like you've resolved that final issue I wasn't figuring out with the `offset()`... will delete my work-in-progress of trying to figure out what was going on

Comment: @OnTheHunt if it worked please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner However, the table filter isn't working. I want to apply the table filter

Comment: you will  need to rerun the code manually or put the live formula in instead.